# How to setup iptables to feed squid proxy server?

Tags: iptables, raspbian, squid

I am following this https://raspberrytips.com/raspberry-pi-firewall/ to setup `iptables` for squid proxy server.

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i wlan0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to 192.168.42.1:3128
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3128
```

This commands should send data to squid at por 3128 but squid receives no data. I know Squid is working fine, because it receives data if i setup the browser to user 192.168.42.1:3128 as proxy

Current version of iptables is 1.8.2

Comment: Are you testing from the pi itself?

Comment: from outside, wlan0

Comment: So are you seeing a squid generated error page? Have you configured squid to work as a transparent proxy? (i.e. add another `http_port` with the option `intercept` and DNAT/REDIRECT traffics to that port instead.)

Comment: I am not following. I don't see squid generate a error page, Simply the information doesn't reach his port. I am trying to use as a transparent proxy, that's why i am using the PREROUTING iptable entrys above.

Comment: Perhaps you should update your question with `iptables-save` output and the content of your squid.conf. Maybe also the "information" you mentioned (a screenshot of the browser?).

Comment: `tcpdump -ni any tcp port 80` capture when you try to access a site might help as well